# Sequence of CSS element

Tags: css

There are two CSS statements but different sequence order in declaration.

```
.wrap {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    min-height:600px;
    background: url('/images/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
.wrap {
    background: url('/images/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    min-height:600px;
}
```

The difference is just the sequence order of the element between `background: url()` and `background-color`, if `background: url()` is declared after the `background-color` and there is no image can be loaded, then the `background-color` cannot become effective. It seems the `background: url()` override the `background-color`.

Demo can be found from http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/ctgc8xzL/

Is there any definition to the CSS syntax about the element sequence order in declaration? I read the w3schools.com but no such information.

Comment: You're mixing longhand and shorthand CSS syntax. For simplicity, pick one.

Comment: Solution: dont use w3schools.com - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the shortcut `background` property, any unspecified background properties such as `background-color` are set to the initial default value.

So if the `background` property is declared after `background-color` without specifying 
a color, then the background color takes on the initial value of `transparent`.

This is part of the CSS specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

Answer (score 0):

`background` is just a short-hand for a multiple of attributes

```css
body {
    background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

What you want is to set

`background-image: url()` seperately. or just use the combined one for all your values.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asks about the cascading nature of CSS.

Comment: OP is clearly mixing up shorthands vs "longhands" together. Cascading is not his concern.

Comment: "Is there any definition to the CSS syntax about the **element sequence order** in declaration?" This quote from the OP suggests otherwise.

Comment: @TylerH, sigh you downvoted my answer just so you can come up with your own one?

Comment: No, I downvoted your answer because it doesn't answer the question. if you hover over the downvote, you'll see a popup with its intended purpose.

Comment: I suspect the OP doesn't understand the `background` is a shorthand property and that omitting a value in a shorthand property sets it to its `initial value`, which in the case of [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) is `transparent` but we can let the OP decide by voting.

Comment: TylerH and xiamx, thanks you two giving me the clear concept. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

CSS is short for **Cascading** Style Sheets (emphasis mine). This means that selectors and properties listed later will override selectors/properties that came before.

Think of it as if someone tells you "go left, and then right. Wait; nevermind. Go right, and then right again". You would follow the second set of instructions, rather than the first. CSS works the same way.

So with the following CSS:

```
div {
    color: green;
    color: red;
}
```

The `color: red;` will be applied, whereas `color: green;` will be overridden.

Usually, there is *no requirement* to order certain properties certain ways; you can put `width` before `height` or vice versa, and you could put `background: url()` after `background-color`. No big deal; the CSS will be applied the same way.

On a slightly different note, there are some *selectors* that require a particular ordering. That is, `a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active` should be placed in that order to avoid specificity problems.

Answer (score 0):

The [cascading rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) of CSS specify that other things being equal, the latter of two conflicting declarations wins. And here other things are equal, since the declarations for `background` and `background-color` appear within the same rule, so they have the same status (same source, same importance, same specificity).

The declarations are in conflict, since they both set the background color. The reason as that the [`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background) shorthand property always sets all background properties. When the background color is not specified when using the shorthand, it is set to the initial value, `transparent` (which, when it takes effect, means that the background of the enclosing element shines through).

Thus, although the first version of the code is valid, too, it is pointless in the sense that the `background-color` declaration cannot have any effect. The second version sets first all background properties and then overrides the background color with another declaration. This is a possible coding style, though some people may say it is not good style.

The issue does not arise if you set background image using the specific `background-image` property instead of the shorthand. (A background image may cause that the background color is not seen, if the image fills the entire element area, but that’s a different issue.)